# How can I use innerHTML in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

My problem is that I don't know how to show the `innerHTML` of my form.

The form is like a survey form and once you clicked the submit button, all the contents I had answered would show like a summary page...

```
function displayResult() {
  var first = document.getElementById("first").value;
  var middle = document.getElementById("middle").value;
  var last = document.getElementById("last").value;
  var maincontent = document.getElementById("content").innerHTML;
  maincontent = "<p>" + first;
}
```

Comment: For one I'd get rid of that trailing `"`.

Comment: Check out JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net) and put an example of your HTML and JS, so that we can see what DOM you're working with

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8TtxV/ here it is :(

Comment: [`element.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.innerHTML) is a *property*, with a *getter* and *setter*. You can't get a reference to it as a node, because when you call it directly like `var content = domelement.innerHTML;`, you *get* it's value in a string, **not** a reference to it like a function. So you have to pass the `.innerHTML` down to the next line and use it with the node reference.

Comment: @JaredFarrish yes yes, now i understand it. thanks you so much and for the good help anyway..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var maincontent = document.getElementById("content").innerHTML;
maincontent = "<p>" + first;
```

On the second line you're overwriting the variable, not setting the `.innerHTML`. This is what you want:

```
var maincontent = document.getElementById("content");
maincontent.innerHTML = "<p>" + first;
```

Also, you must make sure the elements with ids of "first" "middle" and "last" actually exist, or this might cause a `TypeError`.

Comment: @ghie Make sure you have an element with an id equal to "content". Like this: `id="content"`. Also, make sure the elements with ids of "first" "middle" and "last" actually exist.

Comment: oh.. i see. thank you! i think i forgot the id thing -.- thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```js
function displayResult() {
  var first = document.getElementById("first").value;

  var maincontent = "";
  maincontent = "<p>" + first + "</p>";
  document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = maincontent;

}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="first" value="good">
<button onclick="displayResult();">Click me!!!</button>
<div id="content"></div>
```

But, you should have `id` as first.
and you should need content `div` in html part.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
var maincontent = document.getElementById("content").innerHTML;
maincontent = "<p>" + first;`
```

Try this:

```
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = "<p>" + first;
```

You may also want to use .innerHTML to get 'first', rather than .value? I'm not sure what kind of element 'first' is.

Comment: thanks! i tried it already but it doesn't display anything :( what do you think is the problem with that? sorry... i've been just new in javascript.. :(

Answer (score 0):

What is your element with id "contend" , a div? td? tr? or ? The way it should be is

```
 <div id='content'> 
   </div>
```

and then this is the javascript code

```
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = "<p>" + first + middle + last + "</p>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use the [`setHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setHTML) method instead of innerHTML internally. You can check the browser support for [setHTML](https://caniuse.com/?search=setHTML).

```js
function displayResult() {
  const first = document.getElementById("first").value;
  const maincontent = document.getElementById("content")
  maincontent.setHTML("<p>" + first)
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="first" value="<p>We <em>had</em> to do something about it.</p>">
<button type="button" onclick="displayResult()">Submit</button>
<div id="content"></div>
```