# How to make plain text to html javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var innerHtml ='<td>'+ getResponse[i].note +'</td>'
                                    + '<td>'+ getResponse[i].id +'</td>'
                                    + '<td>'+ getResponse[i].date +'</td>'
                                    + '<td>'+ '#' +'</td>';

var table = document.getElementById('table').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
                                var newRow   = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);
                                var newText  = document.createTextNode(innerHtml);
                                newRow.appendChild(newText);
```

variable innerhtml is added in html innerhtml but innerhtml is not perceived as html ,it's perceived as plain text...

Comment: You are turning it into a text node with `document.createTextNode(innerHtml)`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12653292/how-can-i-use-innerhtml-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text nodes are text nodes. If you want element nodes, then create element nodes. Don't build a string of text and try to transform it.

```
var newRow   = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);

var note = document.createElement('td');
note.appendChild(document.createTextNode(getResponse[i].note));
newRow.appendChild(note);

var id = document.createElement('td');
id.appendChild(document.createTextNode(getResponse[i].id));
newRow.appendChild(id);

var date = document.createElement('td');
date.appendChild(document.createTextNode(getResponse[i].date));
newRow.appendChild(date);

var poundSymbol = document.createElement('td');
poundSymbol.appendChild(document.createTextNode("#"));
newRow.appendChild(poundSymbol);
```

Comment: Some mistakes in that code, but the spirit of it is correct.  I'm curious whether or not you feel that JQuery overuses innerHTML too.